# Using same seed for two different random generators

Tags: python-2.7

I have a script that generates random numbers with seed time(0). Now I want to write other script that executes the first script and has the same seed. I want both the scripts to generate same random numbers.
Can I do this?

Edit: The first script is in c++ and cannot be modified. I  want to write a python script to do as described above

Comment: If you want a consistent seed, don't use time(0). (Since when is time(0) Python, anyway?)

Comment: The first script isn't in python. Its in c++. I want to make a python script that executes the first one and want both to generate same random numbers

Comment: If you can modify the C++ program it would be cleanest to add a parameter/configuration option to pass a custom seed.

Comment: The C++ program cannot be modified

Comment: I'd doubt that your C++ standard library and Python have the same random number generator, so even if you did use the same seeds, you still wouldn't get the same random numbers.

Comment: In python in order to initialize the random generator state, there is `random.seed` A bit of code would be good!